# Can I display local machine time zone on a server's shared drive?

Tags: terminal, timezone, timestamp, citrix

I have a network set up where I have an application server with a shared drive and users access the shared drive through a terminal server. I work for a global company so timezones vary when it comes to file timestamps. Is there any way I can have user local machine timestamp displayed when the files are modified on the shared drive?

We are using windows server 2008 R2 64 bit, and the terminal servers are utilizing citrix xenapp 6.5.

Answer (score 3):

Time zone redirection is supported on XenApp and RDS, you need to set up policies for such. That said, I am researching issues with JAVA applications in particluar that do not respect these policies, so you still may be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

No, the file server has no knowledge of the terminal server's client's time zone.